# How to efficiently combine multiple pandas columns into one array-like column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

It is easy to create (or load) a DataFrame with something like an object-typed column, as so:

```py
[In]: pdf = pd.DataFrame({
                     "a": [1, 2, 3], 
                     "b": [4, 5, 6], 
                     "c": [7, 8, 9], 
                     "combined": [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]}
      )

[Out]
   a  b  c   combined
0  1  4  7  [1, 4, 7]
1  2  5  8  [2, 5, 8]
2  3  6  9  [3, 6, 9]
```

I am currently in the position where I have, as separate columns, values that I am required to return as a single column, and need to do so quite efficiently. Is there a fast and efficient way to combine columns into a single object-type column?

In the example above, this would mean already having columns `a`, `b`, and `c`, and I wish to create `combined`.

I failed to find a similar example of question online, feel free to link if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using numpy on large data it is much faster than rest

Update -- numpy with list comprehension is much faster takes only 0.77s

```
pdf['combined'] = [x for x in pdf[['a', 'b', 'c']].to_numpy()]
# pdf['combined'] = pdf[['a', 'b', 'c']].to_numpy().tolist()
```

Comparision of speed

```py
import pandas as pd
import sys
import time

def f1():
    pdf = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]*1000000,  "b": [4, 5, 6]*1000000,  "c": [7, 8, 9]*1000000})
    s0 = time.time()
    pdf.assign(combined=pdf.agg(list, axis=1))
    print(time.time() - s0)

def f2():
    pdf = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]*1000000,  "b": [4, 5, 6]*1000000,  "c": [7, 8, 9]*1000000})
    s0 = time.time()
    pdf['combined'] = [x for x in pdf[['a', 'b', 'c']].to_numpy()]
    # pdf['combined'] = pdf[['a', 'b', 'c']].to_numpy().tolist()
    print(time.time() - s0)

def f3():
    pdf = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]*1000000,  "b": [4, 5, 6]*1000000,  "c": [7, 8, 9]*1000000})
    s0 = time.time()
    cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    pdf['combined'] = pdf[cols].apply(lambda row: list(row.values), axis=1)
    print(time.time() - s0)

def f4():
    pdf = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]*1000000,  "b": [4, 5, 6]*1000000,  "c": [7, 8, 9]*1000000})
    s0 = time.time()
    pdf["combined"] = pdf.apply(pd.Series.tolist,axis=1)
    print(time.time() - s0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    eval(f'{sys.argv[1]}()')
```

```
➜   python test.py f1
17.766116857528687
➜   python test.py f2
0.7762737274169922
➜   python test.py f3
14.403311252593994
➜   python test.py f4
12.631694078445435
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `DataFrame.agg` and pass list as aggregate method, with `axis=1`, then assign it to a new column

```py
>>> pdf.assign(combined=pdf.agg(list, axis=1))

   a  b  c   combined
0  1  4  7  [1, 4, 7]
1  2  5  8  [2, 5, 8]
2  3  6  9  [3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: Can you please explain the **downvote**? The random downvotes on all the answer and question. Is it a new tend on SO?

Comment: @eroot163pi, IDK, may be someone is enjoying downvoting randomly.

Comment: @eroot163pi, o it's not OP

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will be fast enough for your purpose but you might use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` (i.e. apply function to row) combined with [`pandas.Series.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6],"c":[7,8,9]})
df["combined"] = df.apply(pd.Series.tolist,axis=1)
print(df)
```

output

```
   a  b  c   combined
0  1  4  7  [1, 4, 7]
1  2  5  8  [2, 5, 8]
2  3  6  9  [3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6],"c":[7,8,9]})
df['combined'] = [list(row) for _, row in df.iterrows()]
```

output

```
   a  b  c   combined
0  1  4  7  [1, 4, 7]
1  2  5  8  [2, 5, 8]
2  3  6  9  [3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for you is to use `pandas.DataFrame.apply` on the columns that need to be combined. So something like this:

```
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df['combined'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: list(row.values), axis=1)
```

output:

```
    a   b   c   combined
0   1   4   7   [1, 4, 7]
1   2   5   8   [2, 5, 8]
2   3   6   9   [3, 6, 9]
```

After that you can use the `pandarallel` (https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel) library to run the apply in parallel with:

```
from pandarallel import pandarallel
pandarallel.initialize()

cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df['combined'] = df[cols].parallel_apply(lambda row: list(row.values), axis=1)
```

This should prove to be the fastest way on a large amount of data.