# how to speed up pandas rolling argmax?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a long pandas Series.

For Example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: a = pd.DataFrame(range(100000000))
```

i want to get the max element's index in a rolling 10 list.

I tried:

```
In [8]: a[0].rolling(10).apply(lambda x: x.idxmax())
```

and

```
In [9]: a[0].rolling(10).apply(np.argmax)
```

both of them are too slow to run, is there any method can make this work in a standable time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numba engine for fast calculations, you will get results fast as compared without using numba, other than numba there is cython optimization also.

Numba works very well with numpy, and pandas work well with numpy, sometime you can do a.to_numpy and do you calculation in numpy using or not using numba and reassign back to pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame(range(10000000))
a.rolling(10).apply(np.argmax, engine='numba', raw=True)
```

PS: look at my answer at [How to efficiently combine multiple pandas columns into one array-like column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68741389/how-to-efficiently-combine-multiple-pandas-columns-into-one-array-like-column/68741779#68741779) for efficient conversion from pandas to numpy

Comment: Hi, eroot, do you know how to speed up argsort? `a.rolling(10).apply(lambda x: np.argsort(x)[-1], engine='numba', raw=True)` seems slow.

Comment: I am not exactly sure on this, but when trying to use custom function using lambda which is not optimized it tend to be slower. I just got myself into performance optimization so not exactly sure, but for speed I would always prefer something inbuilt

Comment: I will update when I know more on exact reason. Infact your question can be a new valid question as to why lamda is slow. even lambda x: np.argmax(x) is slow actually compared to direct usage of np.argmax. May be it has something to do with lambda being a function calling another function so lambda setup one more stack??

Comment: argsort requires sorting thats why it is slow and takes time